# angularJS - can you watch a function call?

Tags: angularjs

wondering if there is a way in angular to watch a function like you would a variable

```
function foo() {
    console.log("foo called");
}

$scope.$watch('foo', function {
    console.log("foo watched");
});
```

So given the syntax is correct, will "foo watched" be printed to the console, if not, is there a way to have that watch function run?

**EDIT**

Reformatting question to more of what I need:

Let's say I have a button and an text input, each handled by different controllers, say `btnCtrl` and `txtCtrl`

There is also a boolean global flag stored as `$scope.flag` which changes the validation standards for the input.

```
//btnCtrl

//called on button click
function onButtonClick() {
    $scope.flag = !$scope.flag
}

//txtCtrl

//called on input change
function onInputChange() {
    handleValidations()
}

function handleValidations() {
    //set error indicator on invalid input
    //valid input changes based on $scope.flag value
    if($scope.flag) {
        //check validation1
    } else {
        //check validation2
    }
}
```

I want to check the input box validations, `handleValidations` when `$scope.flag` is changed. `$scope.flag` is changed frequently not by the button, but by other functions.

So, I would like to call `handleValidations` not when `$scope.flag` is changed, but when `onButtonClick` is called. What is the best way to do that?

My initial thought was to put some sort of `$scope.$watch` on `onButtonClick`.

Comment: Why can't you just invoke another one function inside `foo`?

Comment: If you want to know if the function `foo` was fired, you can call [`$rootScope.$broadcast`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$broadcast) inside it and listen for that event with [`$scope.$on`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$on)

Comment: @AlekseySolovey That would work but trying to limit number of `$rootscope` calls, do you think there's another way?

Comment: @CommercialSuicide The `$watch` is in a controller and `foo` is in a model. `foo` is only invoked on a button press handled by a different controller.

Comment: @ConorMaley it [would be best](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) if you can **describe what you want to do** in the first place. Perhaps you want to execute function `bar` after `foo`, then you can chain them with [`$q` promises](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q)

Comment: @AlekseySolovey Yes, I was not specific enough, editing the post now

Comment: @ConorMaley I think it's the typical case of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21919962/share-data-between-angularjs-controllers). Services are running in a different _layer_ and therefore can allow your controllers to communicate and share common variables. You should possibly change the code to have `YourService.flag = !YourService.flag` and `if(YourService.flag){...}`

Comment: @AlekseySolovey Yes that is another option, I am in too deep with the number of functions that touch the flag, so in hindsight, I should've done some better architecture-ing. The broadcast/listening approach you first suggested worked for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the help of the comments and other answers:

I sent a local message using `$rootscope` from `btnCtrl` and added a listener to `txtCtrl` that calls `handleValidations`

Thank you all for the help

Answer (score 1):

You can watch the functions. Have you tried running your code? If you call foo, it should print both console statements. There is a 'gotcha' for watching functions though, [mastering $watch in Angularjs](https://www.sitepoint.com/mastering-watch-angularjs/)

> One key aspect to note here, is that if the expression is evaluated as a function, then that function needs to be idempotent. In other words, for the same set of inputs it should always return the same output. If this is not the case, Angular will assume that the data being watched has changed. In turn, this means that it will keep detecting a difference and call the listener at every iteration of the digest cycle.